# How to show one selected value in JSF 1.2 selectOneMenu list from database

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am working in JSF 1.2

I have populated a list using `selectOneMenu` from database. Now my requirement is that, among that list coming from the database, there is one value which have to be shown as selected. But I can not do that.

I am posting my code what I have done so far,

My bean code

```
 mem = new MemberProxy().getMemberDetails(loggedInUser
                        .getUserAccessList().get(0).getClientCode(), loggedInUser
                        .getUserAccessList().get(0).getCertificateNumber());

             memberDependent.setInsuredMemberName(new SelectItem(mem.getNameFirst()));
```

My JSP code

```
 <h:panelGroup styleClass="panelGroup" id="grpMemDep"> 
                                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{searchUserProfileBean.insuredMemberName}" id="memDepCode" styleClass="inputfont" onchange="getMemberDepInfo();" >                                             
                                                    <f:selectItems id="selectItems32"
                                                        value="#{searchUserProfileBean.memberDependentList}" />
                                                </h:selectOneMenu>

                                        </h:panelGroup>
```

This is the way how i am constructing the list

```
 MemberDependentBO memberDependent = new MemberDependentBO();

            List<DependentDTO> dependentList = new MemberProxy()
            .getDependentListFormMember( loggedInUser
                    .getUserAccessList().get(0).getClientCode(),
                    loggedInUser
                    .getUserAccessList().get(0).getCertificateNumber());
            List<SelectItem> selList=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

            for(DependentDTO depDTO:dependentList){

                SelectItem sel = new SelectItem();
                sel.setLabel(depDTO.getNameFirst());
                sel.setValue(depDTO.getCertNumber()+"#"+depDTO.getClientCode()+"#"+depDTO.getDependentCode());
                selList.add(sel);   
            }
             mem = new MemberProxy().getMemberDetails(loggedInUser
                        .getUserAccessList().get(0).getClientCode(), loggedInUser
                        .getUserAccessList().get(0).getCertificateNumber());

             memberDependent.setInsuredMemberName(new SelectItem(mem.getNameFirst()));
             SelectItem sel = new SelectItem();
             sel.setLabel(mem.getNameFirst());
             sel.setValue(mem.getCertNumber().toString().trim()+"#"+mem.getClientCode().toString().trim());
             selList.add(sel);

            memberDependent.setMemberDependentList(selList);
```

Here I  have used one `selectItem` type variable which I am setting to my bean and that I am trying to show in the list but it is not working.

Comment: Here you have a lot of information related to "selectOneMenu" http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info Including how to set a selected item.

Comment: @RubioRic can you edit my code i am totally clueless

Comment: In the examples that appears in the link, the selected item is a simple String. Have you tried using a String in  searchUserProfileBean.insuredMemberName?

Comment: Is searchUserProfileBean.memberDependentList a list of String or a list of Selecttem?

Comment: @RubioRic searchUserProfileBean.memberDependentList  is a list of selectitem

Comment: @RubioRic yes i  have tried with String but it did not work

Comment: Show how your are constructing that list. Maybe this will give us a hint.

Comment: @RubioRic i have edited my list population please see

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, sorry. Let me insist, in all the examples that I've checked the initial selected value is a String and not a SelectItem.  "memberDependent.setInsuredMemberName(mem.getNameFirst());" should do the work.

Comment: The only strange thing is that you are constructing item values in slightly different way. [ONE] sel.setValue(depDTO.getCertNumber()+"#"+depDTO.getClientCode()+"#"+depDTO.getDependentCode()); [TWO] sel.setValue(mem.getCertNumber().toString().trim()+"#"+mem.getClientCode().toString().trim());

Comment: @RubioRic that's for a reason  i have to send the clientcode and certno for  data polulation

Comment: But why do you construct the items differently in these two cases?

Comment: @RubioRic  i am  new to jsf , can you please edit my code?

Comment: I've tried to explain myself in an answer. Check it, try it and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Let me mark three points of your code

```
 for (DependentDTO depDTO:dependentList){
   SelectItem sel = new SelectItem();
   sel.setLabel(depDTO.getNameFirst());
   sel.setValue(depDTO.getCertNumber()+"#"+depDTO.getClientCode()+"#"+depDTO.getDependentCode());
   selList.add(sel);  // [1]
 }

 mem = new MemberProxy().getMemberDetails(loggedInUser
                    .getUserAccessList().get(0).getClientCode(), loggedInUser
                    .getUserAccessList().get(0).getCertificateNumber());

memberDependent.setInsuredMemberName(new SelectItem(mem.getNameFirst())); // [2]

SelectItem sel = new SelectItem();
sel.setLabel(mem.getNameFirst());
sel.setValue(mem.getCertNumber().toString().trim()+"#"+mem.getClientCode().toString().trim());
         selList.add(sel); // [3]

memberDependent.setMemberDependentList(selList);
```

[1] Is the value that you want to select already in this list?

[2] You are creating and item with no established value. Item value will be equal to item label: mem.getNameFirst()

[3] At this point you are including an item with the **same label** but with a **different value** that the one generated in [2]. Besides the value generated is different from the value generated in [1]

```
sel.setValue(depDTO.getCertNumber()+"#"+depDTO.getClientCode()+"#"+depDTO.getDependentCode());
sel.setValue(mem.getCertNumber().toString().trim()+"#"+mem.getClientCode().toString().trim());
```

In the second sentence you are trimming and not including the third element "dependentCode"

Try this

```
  SelectItem sel = new SelectItem();
  sel.setLabel(mem.getNameFirst());
  // INCLUDE DEPENDENT CODE
  sel.setValue(mem.getCertNumber()+"#"+mem.getClientCode()+"#"+mem.getDependentCode());  

  memberDependent.setInsuredMemberName(sel);

  selList.add(sel); // ONLY, ONLY IF ITEM IS NOT INCLUDE IN LOOP [1]

  memberDependent.setMemberDependentList(selList);
```